# COMMIT SQL TRANSACTION IN ROLLBACK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have created stored procedure with `TRY CATCH`. In `CATCH` section i am executing another stored procedure to store error in table `Error_Details`.

Now in C#, I am using `DbTransaction` to commit and rollback depend upon error.

Problem is, while rollback changes table `Error_Details` also getting rolled back.

Is there any option where everything should rolled back but not `Error_Details` table?

Comment: I guess the approach should be to either do transaction handling at the C# side or at the db side and don't mix the two. 
If you want DbTransaction at C# side, remove the try catch from the sp and execute error logging as a separate call from the C# side. Or alternatively, do the entire transaction handling within the SP and do away with DbTransaction from C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transactions inside the stored procedure itself.
Please see one sample case below.

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION MyActivity

   -- Your SQL COMMANDS

 COMMIT TRANSACTION MyActivity
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyActivity    
   END 
    INSERT INTO ERROR_DETAILS --INSERTING ErrorInfo INTO LOG TABLE
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
```